# Converting png to tensor for machine learning

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert png file from bing image search API into a tensor so that I can run it through a number recognition model for machine learning called MNIST. I am having trouble with conversation and encountered this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Running it in python in GCP juypternotebook.

```
key = os.environ.get('AZURE_SEARCH_KEY', 'b3a6daaa4ce340d0a7acb03de1fc94b2')
results = search_images_bing(key, '3')
ims = results.attrgot('contentUrl')
len(ims)

dest = 'images/3.jpg'
download_url(ims[0], dest)

df = pd.DataFrame(tensor(im))
df.style.set_properties(**{'font-size':'1pt'}).background_gradient('Blues')
```

Here's the error I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdPpj.png)

Comment: `from PIL import Image image = Image.open(file) img_array = np.array(image) tf.convert_to_tensor(arg, dtype=tf.float32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code which converts image to Tensor

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('img.png')
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(im)
array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
tensor_img = tf.convert_to_tensor(array, dtype=tf.float32)
tensor_img
```

**Output**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(168, 300, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[137., 133., 121.],
        [137., 133., 121.],
        [138., 134., 122.],
        ...,
        [112., 109.,  92.],
        [112., 109.,  92.],
        [112., 109.,  92.]],

       [[137., 133., 121.],
        [137., 133., 121.],
        [138., 134., 122.],
        ...,
        [112., 109.,  92.],
        [112., 109.,  92.],
        [112., 109.,  92.]],

       [[137., 133., 121.],
        [137., 133., 121.],
        [138., 134., 122.],
        ...,
        [112., 109.,  92.],
        [112., 109.,  92.],
        [112., 109.,  92.]],

       ...,

       [[203., 187., 154.],
        [201., 185., 152.],
        [198., 181., 151.],
        ...,
        [206., 188., 166.],
        [205., 187., 165.],
        [205., 187., 163.]],

       [[208., 192., 159.],
        [206., 190., 157.],
        [203., 186., 156.],
        ...,
        [206., 188., 166.],
        [206., 188., 166.],
        [206., 188., 164.]],

       [[210., 194., 161.],
        [208., 192., 159.],
        [205., 188., 158.],
        ...,
        [207., 189., 167.],
        [206., 188., 166.],
        [206., 188., 164.]]], dtype=float32)>
```